# Incorrect Query Results on Opportunity?

Tags: apex, soql, query

My code is pulling through `Opportunity` records where the `StageName` is equal to `'Closed won - Signed Contract'` or `'Closed Lost'`. However it shouldn't be pulling through these records. What is wrong with my query?

```
 listOpportunity = [SELECT Id, OwnerId,Name,Owner.FirstName,(SELECT Id, Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems
                                                            WHERE Product2.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue_Emailed__c = FALSE
                                                            AND Product2.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue_Initiated__c = TRUE)
                                                            FROM Opportunity
                                                            WHERE (StageName != 'Closed Won - Signed Contract' OR StageName != 'Closed Lost')
                                                            AND Id in
                                                                       (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem
                                                                        WHERE Product2.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue_Emailed__c = FALSE
                                                                        AND Product2.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue_Initiated__c = TRUE)];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a logical perspective, any time you have a statement of the form `X != A || X != B`, it will always return true unless `A = B`. For instance, if your `StageName` equals `"Closed Lost"`, then it does not equal `"Closed Won - Signed Contract"`. The `StageName` is *always* going to *not match* one of those values, since it can't be both at the same time. So that `OR` clause will select every record.

When matching on one field, use `IN` and `NOT IN` operators.

```
StageName NOT IN ('Closed Won - Signed Contract', 'Closed Lost')
```

If you really wanted separate clauses, `AND` would be the correct operator to join them, since it should be `X != A && X != B`, which is true whenever X does not match `A` and does not match `B`.

```
StageName != 'Closed Won - SignedContract' AND StageName != 'Closed Lost'
```